# BLE service advertisement with Intent on connection in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm working on an idea that requires the Android phone to advertise a BLE service. I was able to start advertising using the [`startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html#startAdvertising(android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseCallback)) API from [`BluetoothLeAdvertiser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser).

The advertisement seems to remain activated definitely as long as the app is not killed so Doze mode does not seem to affect it. The problem is that as soon as I kill the app, the advertisement stops.

Ideally, I would like to hand-off the advertisement to the OS and get an intent when a device attempts to connect. There is an API that does exactly that on the scanner side in [`BluetoothLeScanner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner): [`public int startScan (List<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, PendingIntent callbackIntent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is an equivalent on the advertisement side.

Am I missing something? Logically this should be possible. If it's not, what is the recommended solution to keep the advertisement active reliably in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Foreground Service to keep the app alive. I don't think you can use the Intent method for advertising.

Comment: Yes I was experimenting with this yesterday. The foreground service does the job, not great since the notification is somewhat intrusive though. At the moment I have not found a better solution.